# dplyr giving different results with the rowwise operator than looping that function over each row

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a data frame of taxonomic variables that looks like this (but longer).

```
taxTest <- structure(list(Kingdom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Bacteria", class = "factor"), 
Phylum = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bacteroidetes", 
"Proteobacteria"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bacteroidia", "Gammaproteobacteria"
), class = "factor"), Order = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Bacteroidales", "Enterobacteriales"), class = "factor"), 
Family = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Bacteroidaceae", 
"Enterobacteriaceae", "Prevotellaceae"), class = "factor"), 
Genus = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Bacteroides", 
"Escherichia/Shigella", "Prevotella"), class = "factor"), 
Genus.y = structure(c(NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bacteroides", 
"Prevotella"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("albertii/boydii/coli/coli,/dysenteriae/enterica/fergusonii/flexneri/sonnei/vulneris", 
"copri", "disiens", "dorei", "dorei/vulgatus"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Kingdom", 
"Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", "Genus", "Genus.y", "Species"
), row.names = c("tax1", "tax2", "tax3", "tax4", "tax5"), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: taxTest_output]

I want to come up with a short taxonomic name from this data and so I run a function that is slightly more complicated than this one (it has to deal with deal with NA data in a bunch of these taxonomic levels), but fails in the same way.

```
library(dplyr)

tag_taxon <- function(tvdf){
    species <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Species) %>% unlist

    genus2 <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Genus, Genus.y) %>% unlist
    genus <- genus2 %>% na.omit %>% .[1]

    #genus <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Genus) %>% unlist

        out <- paste(genus, species)

out }
```

If I run this function against each row of the table, I get an answer that I am expecting, a Genus and species name.

```
for(i in 1:5){
    print(taxTest %>% .[i,] %>% tag_taxon)
}
```

> [1] "Escherichia/Shigella albertii/boydii/coli/coli,/dysenteriae/enterica/fergusonii/flexneri/sonnei/vulneris"
>
> [1] "Bacteroides dorei"
>
> [1] "Prevotella copri"
>
> [1] "Bacteroides dorei/vulgatus"
>
> [1] "Prevotella disiens"

I feel like I should be able to use dplyr to apply this function over each row of the data frame. Unfortunately, this returns counter-intuitive results.

```
 taxTest %>% rowwise %>% tag_taxon
```

> 'Escherichia/Shigella albertii/boydii/coli/coli,/dysenteriae/enterica/fergusonii/flexneri/sonnei/vulneris'
>   'Escherichia/Shigella dorei' 'Escherichia/Shigella copri'
>   'Escherichia/Shigella dorei/vulgatus' 'Escherichia/Shigella disiens'

I thought maybe the apply function might also work here, but this just outright fails with a cryptic error message.

```
 apply(taxTest, 1, tag_taxon)
```

> Error in UseMethod("select_"): no applicable method for 'select_'
>   applied to an object of class "character" Traceback:
>
> 1. apply(taxTest, 1, tag_taxon)
> 2. FUN(newX[, i], ...)
> 3. tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Species) %>% unlist   # at line 4 of file
> 4. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
> 5. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 6. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
> 7. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
> 8. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
> 9. function_list[i]
> 10. dplyr::select(., Species)
> 11. select.default(., Species)
> 12. select_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...))

Any ideas about what is going on here? I can totally solve this problem with a for loop, but I'd rather use dplyr if I can.

Thanks!

Edit: One more thing! I forgot to mention in my original post that if one un-comments the `#genus <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Genus) %>% unlist` line (that is, I don't try to append the species information to the genus information) the plyr function gives the expected results.

Comment: Instead of `taxTest %>% select(Species) %>% unlist`, you can do `taxTest %>% pull(Species)`.

Comment: Also, since you've loaded `dplyr`, there's no need to use `dplyr::select` instead of just `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is vectorized, so there's no need for a separate function to operate by row. The code below requires `Genus` and `Genus.y` to be character rather than factor, so I've done the conversion before running the code.

```
taxTest[,c("Genus","Genus.y")] = lapply(taxTest[,c("Genus","Genus.y")] , as.character)

taxTest %>% 
  mutate(tag = gsub("NA ", "", paste(Genus, ifelse(Genus.y==Genus, NA, Genus.y), Species)))
```

The `gsub` is to remove `NA` plus the space after it. Here's what the `tag` column looks like:

> ```
>   tag
> 1 Escherichia/Shigella albertii/boydii/coli/coli,/dysenteriae/enterica/fergusonii/flexneri/sonnei/vulneris
> 2                                                                                        Bacteroides dorei
> 3                                                                                         Prevotella copri
> 4                                                                               Bacteroides dorei/vulgatus
> 5                                                                                       Prevotella disiens
> ```

To see what's going on with your original code, we can add some `cat` statements to `tag_taxon`.

```
tag_taxon <- function(tvdf){
  species <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Species) %>% unlist

  genus2 <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Genus, Genus.y) %>% unlist

  cat("genus2 = ", genus2,"\n")

  genus <- genus2 %>% na.omit %>% .[1]

  cat("genus = ", genus,"\n")

  #genus <- tvdf %>% dplyr::select(Genus) %>% unlist

  out <- paste(genus, species)

  out }

for(i in 1:5){
  print(taxTest %>% .[i,] %>% tag_taxon)
}
```

> ```
> genus2 =  Escherichia/Shigella NA 
> genus =  Escherichia/Shigella
> [1] "Escherichia/Shigella albertii/boydii/coli/coli,/dysenteriae/enterica/fergusonii/flexneri/sonnei/vulneris"
> genus2 =  Bacteroides Bacteroides 
> genus =  Bacteroides 
> [1] "Bacteroides dorei"
> genus2 =  Prevotella Prevotella 
> genus =  Prevotella 
> [1] "Prevotella copri"
> genus2 =  Bacteroides Bacteroides 
> genus =  Bacteroides 
> [1] "Bacteroides dorei/vulgatus"
> genus2 =  Prevotella Prevotella 
> genus =  Prevotella 
> [1] "Prevotella disiens"
> ```

Okay, the for loop is doing what we expect. Now for `dplyr::rowwise`:

```
taxTest %>% rowwise %>% tag_taxon
```

> ```
> genus2 =  Escherichia/Shigella Bacteroides Prevotella Bacteroides Prevotella NA Bacteroides Prevotella Bacteroides Prevotella 
> genus =  Escherichia/Shigella 
> [1] "Escherichia/Shigella albertii/boydii/coli/coli,/dysenteriae/enterica/fergusonii/flexneri/sonnei/vulneris"
> [2] "Escherichia/Shigella dorei"                                                                              
> [3] "Escherichia/Shigella copri"                                                                              
> [4] "Escherichia/Shigella dorei/vulgatus"                                                                     
> [5] "Escherichia/Shigella disiens"
> ```

So `dplyr` is returning as `genus2` a vector with all the values in `Genus` and `Genus.y` concatenated (except for the `NA` values). Then `genus` keeps just the first value and uses it over and over again. This may have something to do with the way `dplyr` performs non-standard evaluation, but I'm not positive.

If you wanted to use your function, it will work the way you expect with `by_row` from the `purrrlyr` package:

```
library(purrrlyr)

taxTest %>% by_row(tag_taxon)
```